# Error when publishing to HTML - DAO.QueryDef System resource exceeded

Tags: enterprise-architect

i'm using Enterprise Architect 15 Corporate edition with local EAP project. Now I am not able export the whole project to HTML (Publish as HTML).
I always get the error message "DAO.QueryDef System resource exceeded" after pressing the button "Generate".

[image]

Checked with OS:
Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit

Any ideas please?

Comment: I would guess you are at the limits of that toy pseudo database. What's its size? Have you run consistency check?